# Wordpress Install hangs on step 2

Tags: wordpress, wampserver

I am trying to install wwordpress-3.7.1 to my local server. But the instillation process hangs on step 2. In step 2 it only shows wordpress logo. When i checked at database, i saw that all the table has install correctly.  Where is the problem?  I have used wamp2.4 for my local server. Please tell me the solution.

Comment: Check out the logs - there should be something explaining the issue. Post them here if you don't understand what do they mean.

Comment: Where can i find the logs?

Comment: Man, have you solved this? Post your answer!

Comment: No,  i didn't find the solution. I am currently using wordpress 3.9.2 and wamp 2.5. Now i don't have any problem. @noitseuq

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, installing WordPress 3.8.1 on Wamp.
Only the logo was displayed on step 2, but only some tables were installed.

In php.ini, I put **90** instead of **30** for **max_execution_time**, like :

```
max_execution_time = 90
```

It solved my case, and hope that will help.

Comment: This worked for me. Changed the file under `bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

Inside wamp folder of you wamp server , you can find logs folder.In logs folder you will be able to see logs of apache,mysql and php.Check these files , you may get some  idea , where its going wrong. Also enable   log errors and display errors of your PHP settings